# Get json data at the end of a file upload data task

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am trying to upload a file to the server and after the completion of upload, I'm supposed to get a JSON response.
I can see the data when I use the completion block

```
uploaderSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                print("\(NSString(data: data!, encoding: 4))")
            }).resume()
```

I need the same data but using the custom delegates

```
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    session.dataTask(with: request).resume()
```

I implemented

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data)
```

but  didReceiveData is not called.
Please suggest what can  be done to get the JSON data at the end of completion of file upload

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ok so got the answer just posting cause it can help somebody

we have to call

```
completionHandler(URLSession.ResponseDisposition.allow)
```

in

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void)
```